# Uisng Json to format and indent in website requests Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, format, tuples

I am trying to indent and assort the format of  `balance` so that it is easier to read. I want to print the `RequestResponse` like the `Expected output`. The `balance` variable is of type `tuple`. How could I do such a  thing?

```
import bybit
import json
balance = client.Wallet.Wallet_getBalance(coin="BTC").result()
print(balance)
```

Output:

```
({'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': {'BTC': {'equity': 0.00208347, 'available_balance': 0.00208347, 'used_margin': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.00208347, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 8.347e-05, 'given_cash': 0, 'service_cash': 0}}, 'time_now': '1616685310.655072', 'rate_limit_status': 118, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1616685310652, 'rate_limit': 120}, <bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x000001F5E92EB048>)
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "cross_seq": 11518,
  "data": [
    {
      "price": "2999.00",
      "side": "Buy",
      "size": 9,
      "symbol": "BTCUSD"
    },
    {
      "price": "3001.00",
      "side": "Sell",
      "size": 10,
      "symbol": "BTCUSD"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp_e6": 1555647164875373,
  "topic": "orderBookL2_25.BTCUSD",
  "type": "snapshot"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you provided the wrong expected output since the fields between your output and expected output don't match but in general if you want a better display of a dictionary you can use the `json` package:

```py
response = {'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': '', 'result': {'BTC': {'equity': 0.00208347, 'available_balance': 0.00208347, 'used_margin': 0, 'order_margin': 0, 'position_margin': 0, 'occ_closing_fee': 0, 'occ_funding_fee': 0, 'wallet_balance': 0.00208347, 'realised_pnl': 0, 'unrealised_pnl': 0, 'cum_realised_pnl': 8.347e-05, 'given_cash': 0, 'service_cash': 0}}, 'time_now': '1616685310.655072', 'rate_limit_status': 118, 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1616685310652, 'rate_limit': 120}

import json

json.loads(json.dumps(response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

This will give you the following output:

```
{'ext_code': '',
 'ext_info': '',
 'rate_limit': 120,
 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1616685310652,
 'rate_limit_status': 118,
 'result': {'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00208347,
   'cum_realised_pnl': 8.347e-05,
   'equity': 0.00208347,
   'given_cash': 0,
   'occ_closing_fee': 0,
   'occ_funding_fee': 0,
   'order_margin': 0,
   'position_margin': 0,
   'realised_pnl': 0,
   'service_cash': 0,
   'unrealised_pnl': 0,
   'used_margin': 0,
   'wallet_balance': 0.00208347}},
 'ret_code': 0,
 'ret_msg': 'OK',
 'time_now': '1616685310.655072'}
```

---

Another solution is to use [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

```py
import pprint

pprint.pprint(response)
```

This will give you the following output:

```
{'ext_code': '',
 'ext_info': '',
 'rate_limit': 120,
 'rate_limit_reset_ms': 1616685310652,
 'rate_limit_status': 118,
 'result': {'BTC': {'available_balance': 0.00208347,
                    'cum_realised_pnl': 8.347e-05,
                    'equity': 0.00208347,
                    'given_cash': 0,
                    'occ_closing_fee': 0,
                    'occ_funding_fee': 0,
                    'order_margin': 0,
                    'position_margin': 0,
                    'realised_pnl': 0,
                    'service_cash': 0,
                    'unrealised_pnl': 0,
                    'used_margin': 0,
                    'wallet_balance': 0.00208347}},
 'ret_code': 0,
 'ret_msg': 'OK',
 'time_now': '1616685310.655072'}
```

Comment: Thank you the `pprint` function works. However when i use the json function it gives me the error: `TypeError: Object of type RequestsResponseAdapter is not JSON serializable`.

Comment: On which variable do you apply the json function? the balance from your snippet?

Comment: I applied it to the `response` function. It gets its data from a websites api.

Comment: You may have to convert the output of the request to a json first (the `RequestsResponseAdapter` class may have a method get_json or something like this)

Answer (score 0):

Import JSON, then using `json.dumps(balance, indent=4)` would get you that format.

You could add keyword argument of `sort_keys=True` if you want them sorted.